# WPF TextBox and ComboBox in disabled state (background color does not look the same)

Tags: wpf, combobox, background, textbox, styles

Here is image of my controls when they are disabled:

[image]

As you can see combobox is pretty much different that textbox even if I use same colours etc, I don't know how could I achieve to make them look same?

Here is code of my textbox style:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E0E4E5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E0E4E5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#0091EA"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

AND HERE IS CODE OF MY COMBOBOX:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
      <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E0E4E5" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

What do I need to do to make them look the same when  they are disabled? Somehow colour is not looking as it should be ..

I tried also setting template to my combobox style but than I'm loosing arrow and it look more TextBox than a ComboBox after applying this:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to override the `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` brush:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#E0E4E5" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
...
</ComboBox>
```

This should work on Windows 7. On Windows 8 and later you need to override the entire `ControlTemplate` of the `ComboBox`. You can right-click on the ComboBox element in design mode in Visual Studio 2012 and later and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy to copy the default template into your XAML markup and then edit it as per your requirements. Look for the `IsEnabled` triggers in the `Style` or the `ControlTemplate`.

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/